# Build custom form with entity form field

Tags: entities, forms, 9

I have a feature to migrate from Drupal 7 to Drupal 9. This allows me to build a custom form made up of static fields, which I define in the code of my module, and fields dynamically retrieved from an entity.

It worked with the "ctools_field_invoke_field function", which relies on the Chaos Tools module. This function is itself based on a native Drupal function "field_default_form".

This function was not migrated to Drupal 9 according to my research. Can I find an equivalent? Should I develop this function from scratch?

My previous code :

```
// If no language is provided use the default site language.
$options = array(
  'language' => field_valid_language($langcode),
  'default' => TRUE,
);

// Append to the form
ctools_include('fields');
$field_instance = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle);
return (array) ctools_field_invoke_field($field_instance, 'form', $entity_type, $entity, $form, $form_state, $options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find similar function either. Looks like it does not exist.
Though, here is how it can be achieved in Drupal 8/9 forms:

```
$entity = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->create([
  'type' => 'article'
]);
$form_state->set('entity', $entity);


/** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityFormDisplayInterface $form_display */
$form_display = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('entity_form_display')->load('node.article.custom_form_display');
$form_state->set('form_display', $form_display);

foreach ($form_display->getComponents() as $name => $component) {
  $widget = $form_display->getRenderer($name);
  if (!$widget) {
    continue;
  }

  $items = $entity->get($name);
  $items->filterEmptyItems();
  $form[$name] = $widget->form($items, $form, $form_state);
  $form[$name]['#access'] = $items->access('edit');
}
```

This code was taken from the following article:
https://www.webomelette.com/how-render-entity-field-widgets-inside-custom-form-drupal-8

*I am not affiliated with it, but personally, recommend to read.*